React-datepicker with react 18 and webpack 4.19.1 error
For my react app with react 18 and webpack 4.19.1, i see error when i try to use react-datepicker, i see an error like: o.isValid is not a function react-datepicker.min.js.
This is my component.tsx
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

const DatePickerExample = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = date => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Select a Date</h2>
      <DatePicker selected={selectedDate} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default DatePickerExample;

Heres the webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
           options: { presets:["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react","@babel/preset-typescript"]}
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader':
                      { loader:'css-loader', options: 
                       {modules:true}}],
      },
    ],
  },
};

My webpack has babelloader, cssloader.
1.Am not sure why is the react datepicker showing error?
2.Same version works with nextjs
Please help.. thanks in advance..

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, show the webpack config

Hi i added my webpack.config.js..please let me know if anything is required.. thanks!
